# How do I perform a query using ZF2 Firebird_PDO

Tags: php, pdo, zend-framework2, firebird

What am I doing wrong here?

```
$adapter = new Adapter(array(
        'driver'   => 'Pdo_Firebird',
        'database' => 'localhost:c:/firebird/mydb.fdb',
        'username' => 'SYSDBA',
        'password' => 'mypass'
));

$sql = 'SELECT * USERS';
$statement = $adapter->createStatement($sql);
$result = $statement->execute();
```

if I check $result->count() I always get zero (0). However I know this query should produce results.

I get no errors.

Comment: Firebird doesn't know there are results until the rows are fetched. Most drivers for Firebird won't fetch until you actually request rows. Also, the total number of rows produced by a query are not known until all rows have been fetched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, so it appears I am actually getting a result, even though $result->count = 0.

So I have to add the following lines after my code above;

```
$resultSet = new ResultSet;
$resultSet->initialize($result);
foreach ($resultSet as $row)
{
    echo $row->LOGIN . '<BR>';
}
```

Feels a little long winded. Is this the best way to do it? I presume I should add some check to see if any results where returned. But I can't see the correct way to perform this check.